# Expanding pandas dataframe with column range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with column range and strings similar to this:

```
     STREET             LOWADD  HIGHADD POSTAL  SECTOR
0   ABBERLY CIR         1900    2000    23112   A6
1   ABBEY VILLAGE CIR   500     600     23114   B6
```

I need to expand/transform it to the below, between the LOWADD and HIGHADD columns and forward filling the data in STREET, POSTAL and SECTOR:

```
New_Street              POSTAL  SECTOR
1901 ABBERLY CIR        23112   A6
1902 ABBERLY CIR        23112   A6
1903 ABBERLY CIR        23112   A6
1904 ABBERLY CIR        23112   A6
1905 ABBERLY CIR        23112   A6
```

Whats the best way to do this with pandas?

Comment: Did you try anything that went wrong and want to share here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is subtract columns for number of repeated rows by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html), then repeat by [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and last add counter Series by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to `Street` column:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
diff = df['HIGHADD'].sub(df['LOWADD'])
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(diff)]
s = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).add(df['LOWADD']).astype(str)
df['STREET'] = s + ' ' + df['STREET']
df = df.drop(['LOWADD','HIGHADD'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
                    STREET  POSTAL SECTOR
0         1901 ABBERLY CIR   23112     A6
1         1902 ABBERLY CIR   23112     A6
2         1903 ABBERLY CIR   23112     A6
3         1904 ABBERLY CIR   23112     A6
4         1905 ABBERLY CIR   23112     A6
..                     ...     ...    ...
195  596 ABBEY VILLAGE CIR   23114     B6
196  597 ABBEY VILLAGE CIR   23114     B6
197  598 ABBEY VILLAGE CIR   23114     B6
198  599 ABBEY VILLAGE CIR   23114     B6
199  600 ABBEY VILLAGE CIR   23114     B6

[200 rows x 3 columns]
```